# c#: utilizando threads em um projeto "windows forms"

Tags: c#, thread

Em minha aplicação tenho vários "subprocessos". Todos eles emitem informações no qual são exibidas no Form.

Utilizei `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`:

```
Class x {
    public Timer timer {get; set;}

    public void f()
    {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(this.tick);
        timer.Enabled = false;
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private async void tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.status = ProcessoStatus.TRABALHANDO;
        this.timer.Stop();

        await Task.Run(() => this.processo());

        this.timer.Start();
        this.status = ProcessoStatus.OCIOSO;
    }
}
```

Um desses subprocessos faz uma checagem em um webservice procurando por dados atualizados. Mas para isso eu preciso que todos os outros processos parem.

```
// main thread
Class Y
{
    public void a()
    {
        X obj1 = new X();
        X obj2 = new X();
        obj1.f();
        obj2.f();
    }

    public sync()
    {
        obj1.timer.Enabled = false;
        while (obj1.status != ProcessoStatus.OCIOSO)
        {
            // faz nada no loop, apenas aguarda o método tick terminar
        }

        obj2.timer.Enabled = false;
        while (obj2.status != ProcessoStatus.OCIOSO)
        { }

        // pega os dados novos do webservice
    }
 }
```

O problema é que o while, em muitos casos, trava a main thread fazendo com que o "status" nunca fique "ocioso".

Alguma sugestão para melhorar isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que o tick do `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` corre na UI thread - e a UI thread está à espera que o tick acabe. Ou seja, ocorre um deadlock.

A solução é fazer com que a UI thread espere *assincronamente*. Existem várias maneiras de fazer isto, uma delas seria fazer com que cada instancia de `x` exponha uma `Task` que represente o estado do processo (e assim, já nao será necessária a propriedade `status`.

```
class TimedProcess {
    public Timer Timer {get; private set;}

    public Task Completed { get; private set; }

    public TimedProcess()
    {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(this.Tick);
        timer.Enabled = false;
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private async void Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.timer.Stop();

        Completed = Task.Run(() => this.processo());

        await Completed;
        timer.Start();
    }
}


// UI Thread
public async Task Sync()
{
    obj1.Timer.Enabled = false;
    await obj1.Completed;

    obj2.timer.Enabled = false;
    await obj2.Completed;

    // pega os dados novos do webservice
}
```

Assim, o método `Sync` vai libertar a UI thread até que o tick acabe.

Nota que fiz algumas alterações:

- O nome dos métodos em C# são escritos em `PascalCasing` (não em `camelCasing`)
- Movi a criação do timer para o constructor
- Renomeei a classe `x` para `TimedProcess`, para ter um nome mais significativo.